# Static method thread safety

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, static, thread-safety

Let's say I call the following method when a user logs into my mvc application:

```
public static bool IsValidBrowser()
{
    var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;

    if (browser.Browser == "IE") {
        if (browser.MajorVersion < 10) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is this method thread safe? Obviously I'm not modifying anything here, but might it be possible that `HttpContext.Current` changes in the middle of this method?

Would writing the code this way make it thread safe?

```
public ActionResult Login () 
{
    bool validBrowser = IsValidBrowser(HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser);
}

public static bool IsValidBrowser(HttpBrowserCapabilities browser)
{
    if (browser.Browser == "IE") {
        if (browser.MajorVersion < 10) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HttpContext.Current itself is a static method and it'll return the context from the current thread so you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this method thread safe?

Yes this method is thread safe as @DoctorMick already explained. Adding one more point.

> Microsoft’s
>   Framework Class Library (FCL) guarantees that all static methods are thread safe.
>   The FCL had to do this
>   internally because there is no way that multiple companies producing different assemblies could
>   coordinate on a single lock for arbitrating access to the resource.

So if you are using FCL static method you don't need to think about thread safety. eg(Console Class, Math class etc.)